# How to set null in updated_at` field?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I laravel 5.7 app I see that  for some rows

field defined as :

`updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,

has value 0000-00-00 00:00:00

I try to run next statement :

```
DB::table('clients')
  ->where('updated_at','0000-00-00 00:00:00')
  ->update([
      "updated_at" => null
  ]);
```

But got error :

```
: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'updated_at' at row 1 (SQL: update `clients` set `updated_at` =  whe
re `updated_at` = 0000-00-00 00:00:00)
```

Which is correct ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show me how you are currently inserting data? By, the way I am not asking the way of updating `updated_at` column instead how you are inserting data so that some value is being inserted in the table. Also, you can show your migration and model.

Comment: Just gave it a try, should work. Are you sure that particular field can be nullable?